# How do I fix the path of my local git repo after move?

Tags: git, move

How do I fix the path of my local git repo after move?

```
previous local location: /C/website
new local location: /C/Projects/website
remote location: git@bitbucket.org:username/website.git
```

I moved my git repository from one folder `/website` to another `/projects/website` and now I get an error:

```
user@Thinkpad /C/Projects/website (master)
$ git push
fatal: 'C:/website' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there any way to fix this without having to re-clone the project?
I tried:

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in c:/Projects/website/.git/
```

It that did nothing and I got the exact same error again when I tried to push.

**Edit:**

I ran: `git config remote.origin.url C:/Projects/website`. Now when I commit after changing files I get the following reply:

```
user@Thinkpad /C/Projects/website (master)
$ git commit -m "added something"
[master e163ad9] added something
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 something

user@Thinkpad /C/Projects/website (master)
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: OK, this is getting really confusing. What is your local repo, what is the remote?

Comment: Whitecat: did you, by any chance, move the directory and files, but not enter the new directory in your terminal emulator? (the error message kinda suggests this). @fge: yeah, I'm confused too…

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help guys. My knowledge of git is now expanded and I am moving forward!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Run `git config -e` and change the address of the remote, to the correct remote location. In your case that will be `url = git@bitbucket.org:username/website.git` This command will open for editing the `.git/config` file of the repository.

(thanks to @Richard for the command)

Shortcut command:

```
git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:username/website.git
```

Comment: Do I have to do this with every sub directory?

Comment: `git config -e` similarly opens the text editor; you probably want something like `git config remote.origin.url c:/projects/website`

Comment: Now git is not recognizing any of my changes.

Comment: Please be more precise: what do you mean by "not recognizing"? Edit your original post with an example of what you see and explain what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You have to update the `origin` remote to the new url:</s>

```
git remote set-url origin '/C/Projects/website'
```

---

If you just move a local clone, you don't have to do anything to update the pointers to bitbucket or other hosting services. Just move the folder including everything (the `.git` directory is essential).

Comment: This did not change the effect of the commit not working. It still says "Everything up-to-date"

Comment: @Whitecat: if I read your question correctly, you are pushing the repository to itself? What is the current working directory?

Comment: I want to be pushing the project to my repository 'git@bitbucket.org:username/website.git'

Comment: @Whitecat: `git remote set-url origin …` (`… 'git@bitbucket.org:username/website.git'`)

Comment: That last line made the difference. I did move everyting including the .git folder. Can you edit your answer to say what I actually did to fix it? I am still confused as to what was wrong.

Comment: What was wrong, that you edited the url of the `origin` remote in the first place. It does not need to be changed. My comment only showed you, how to _undo_ your problematic change.

Comment: The only time I edited the origin at all was with yours or @Richard 's line of code. But then I am confused as to what was the original problem and how I fixed it.

Comment: Because I thought, you had moved the remote repository, not the repository itself. There was never any need to do anything (except moving the files)

Comment: But I did move the whole directory including the .git folder. That prompted the original question, and error. And by executing: `git config remote.origin.url c:/projects/website`,  `git remote set-url origin '/C/Projects/website'` and `git remote set-url origin … (… 'git@bitbucket.org:username/website.git')` my problem was fixed. I don't think that was the correct solution. But for some reason it did the trick.

Comment: I found a problem! My url = "..." some how initially got confused. It was not set to `git@bitbucket.org:username/website.git`. I don't know when that happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you used **SmartGit** you can change repository url by this way

open smartGit and double click on your repository and go to menu 
`Remote>Properties..` and set new repository path to `path or url.`

Comment: The questioner wanted to move his *local* repository.  So do I.  Your instructions worked great for updating the remote repository (which in my case had also moved), but locally it's still checking out to the old location.